# How to write a Remote DataModule to run on a linux server?

Tags: linux, delphi, datasnap, datamodule

i would like to know if there are any solution to do this. Does anyone?

The big picture: I want to access data over the web, using my delphi thin clients. But i´would like to keep my server/service writen in pascal.

The 'not so' big picture: I´m trying to write a php to emulate a SOAP Midas packets to ClientDataSets in delphi, but i dont have the necessary muscules in my brain to do that. So i could try to convert dbexpress to FPC, but i don´t know if this is legal.

Ok folks, i know that PHP, java, c#/asp, python, ORM´s and things like that could help me with this, but i´m a GUI guy! Everyone who ever programmed 10000 lines report in cobol knows what i´m talking about. I just want to point my soap connection to some server in the net (i dont own the service providers) and make my customers happy. Simple as...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RemObjects SDK](http://www.remobjectssdk.com/) supports Free Pascal. And Free Pascal is a Delphi compatible Pascal compiler for, amongst others, Linux platforms.

http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Introduction_to_Free_Pascal_support

If you are familiar with FPC and don't like to write many lines of code (as you pointed out), I think RemObjects SDK is really an interesting option.

A Delphi cross-platform edition is in the works. Hopefully with the next version of Delphi it is possible to build DataSnap servers for the Linux platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Lazarus and the wst (web service toolkit). We use it for some client / server projects. In Lazarus you can use (almost) 100% compatible Delphi code and you can compile to native apps for Windows, Linux and OSX.

Only problem is the learning curve , which is rather seep.

Comment: How does the Delphi compatibility and the steep learning curve fit together? I'm kind of confused here...

Comment: Freepascal has its own set of componentes. For example the wst I mentioned. It works very good and is under active development, but there is only little documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi 2010 DataSnap support REST protocol and JSON as data packet.  Perhaps this may helps if you want to design your solution to integrate your Delphi apps with non Delphi apps.

Comment: good to know, but i want to integrate different platforms with delphi(pascal)